# Flutter Bloc button toggling

Tags: flutter, boolean, toggle, setstate, bloc

I am trying to get my head around Bloc pattern in flutter. I have managed to create some event handlers for calculations for my app but I can quite figure out how to simply operate a toggle switch to hide/show widgets? Im not sure if I am implementing the toggle switch correctly within the bloc or whether I need to use a void somewhere with the bloc?
Or can I just keep using setState?

Heres what I have so far:

My bloc:

```
    class VelBloc extends Bloc<VelocityEvent, VelocityState> {
     VelBloc() : super(VelocityDataState(answer1: 0, answer2: 0)) {
    on<InitialVelocityEvent>((event, emit) =>
        emit(VelocityDataState(answer1: 0, answer2: 0, standardAir: true)));
    on<StandardAirEvent>((event, emit) =>
        emit(VelocityDataState(answer1: sqrt(event.velocity) * 1.225)));
    on<AirDensityEvent>((event, emit) => emit(
        VelocityDataState(answer2: sqrt(event.velocity) * (event.airDensity))));
    on<IsStandard>(
        (event, emit) => emit(VelocityDataState(standardAir: false)));
          }
      }
```

event:

```
    part of 'vel_air_bloc.dart';

    @immutable
    abstract class VelocityEvent {}

    class InitialVelocityEvent extends VelocityEvent {}

     // ignore: must_be_immutable
    class StandardAirEvent extends VelocityEvent {
     double velocity;
    StandardAirEvent({required this.velocity});
    }

     // ignore: must_be_immutable
    class AirDensityEvent extends VelocityEvent {
     double velocity;
     double airDensity;
    AirDensityEvent({required this.velocity, required this.airDensity});
    }

     // ignore: must_be_immutable
    class IsStandard extends VelocityEvent {
     bool standardAir;
    IsStandard({required this.standardAir});
    }
```

State:

```
    part of 'vel_air_bloc.dart';

    @immutable
    abstract class VelocityState {}

     // ignore: must_be_immutable
     class VelocityDataState extends VelocityState {
     double? answer1;
     double? answer2;
     bool? standardAir;
     VelocityDataState({this.answer1, this.answer2, this.standardAir});
     }
```

Heres the build:

```
     class VelocityAir extends StatefulWidget {
       const VelocityAir({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      State<VelocityAir> createState() => _VelocityAirState();
     }

     class _VelocityAirState extends State<VelocityAir> {
      //bool standard = true; used with setState
      FirebaseServices firebaseServices = FirebaseServices();

      String title = 'Velocity of Air';

      final TextEditingController _velocityController = TextEditingController();
      final TextEditingController _airDensity = TextEditingController();

       @override
       void initState() {
       super.initState();
       context.read<VelBloc>().add(InitialVelocityEvent());
       }

       @override
       void dispose() {
       _velocityController.dispose();
       _airDensity.dispose();
       super.dispose();
      }

      @override
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
        return BlocBuilder<VelBloc, VelocityState>(builder: (context, state) {
         if (state is VelocityDataState) {
           return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text(
              '',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 25,
              ),
            ),
            backgroundColor: ColorConstants.darkScaffoldBackgroundColor,
          ),
          drawer: const CustomDrawer(),
          backgroundColor: ColorConstants.lightScaffoldBackgroundColor,
          body: ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
            children: <Widget>[
              SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: Row(
                  children: const <Widget>[
                    Pagination(
                      nav: 'commissioning_home',
                      buttonColor: ColorConstants.secondaryDarkAppColor,
                      padding: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0)),
                      splashColor: ColorConstants.splashButtons,
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      isIcon: true,
                      icon: Icons.home,
                    ),
                    Pagination(
                      title: 'TAB',
                      nav: 'calculators',
                      buttonColor: ColorConstants.secondaryDarkAppColor,
                      padding: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0)),
                      splashColor: ColorConstants.splashButtons,
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      isIcon: false,
                    ),
                    Pagination(
                      title: 'Air',
                      nav: 'air',
                      buttonColor: ColorConstants.secondaryDarkAppColor,
                      padding: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0)),
                      splashColor: ColorConstants.splashButtons,
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      isIcon: false,
                    ),
                    Pagination(
                      title: 'Airflow & Vel.',
                      nav: 'airflowVel',
                      buttonColor: ColorConstants.secondaryDarkAppColor,
                      padding: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0)),
                      splashColor: ColorConstants.splashButtons,
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      isIcon: false,
                    ),
                    Pagination(
                      title: 'Vel. of Air',
                      nav: 'velOfAir',
                      buttonColor: ColorConstants.messageColor,
                      padding: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0)),
                      splashColor: ColorConstants.splashButtons,
                      textColor: Colors.white,
                      isIcon: false,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  FormulaButton(
                    onPressed: () => openDialog(),
                    formula: r'\sqrt{abc}',
                  ),
                  const Header(title: "Velocity of Air (V)"),
                  AddButton(title: title),
                ],
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Card(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    side: const BorderSide(color: ColorConstants.borderColor),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                  ),
                  color: ColorConstants.secondaryDarkAppColor,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                          child: CustomTextField(
                              onChanged: () {
                                if (_velocityController.text
                                        .trim()
                                        .isNotEmpty &&
                                    standard) {
                                  context.read<VelBloc>().add(StandardAirEvent(
                                      velocity: double.parse(
                                          _velocityController.text)));
                                }
                              },
                              hintText: 'Enter velocity pressure [in Pa]',
                              regExp: RegExp(r'^\d+\.?\d{0,1}'),
                              controller: _velocityController,
                              keyboardType:
                                  const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                                      signed: true, decimal: true),
                              labelText: 'Velocity Pressure (VP)')),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          const Text(
                            "Standard Air?",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              standard == true ? "Yes" : "No",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: standard == true
                                      ? CupertinoColors.activeGreen
                                      : CupertinoColors.destructiveRed,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                            child: CupertinoSwitch(
                                // This bool value toggles the switch.
                                value: standard,
                                thumbColor: Colors.white,
                                trackColor: ColorConstants.borderColor,
                                activeColor: ColorConstants.lightGreen,
                                onChanged: 
                                ),
                          ),
                        ],
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Toggling is just another `event` that should be passed to the `bloc` and the value of the toggle should be emitted in a `state`.

In your case you could add `bool standard` to `VelocityDataState`. Then add a new `event` from `CupertinoSwitch`'s `onChanged` and on your `bloc` you can `copy` the current `VelocityDataState` and only change the `standard` value.

```
class VelocityDataState extends VelocityState {
  double? answer1;
  double? answer2;
  bool? standardAir;
  bool? standard;
  VelocityDataState({this.answer1, this.answer2, this.standardAir, this.standard});

  VelocityDataState copyWith({
    double? answer1,
    double? answer2,
    bool? standardAir,
    bool? standard,
  }) {
    return VelocityDataState(
      answer1: answer1 ?? this.answer1,
      answer2: answer2 ?? this.answer2,
      standardAir: standardAir ?? this.standardAir,
      standard: standard ?? this.standard,
    );
  }
}
```

The `bloc` would look look like this:

```
//...
state = state.copyWith(standard: /*value from toggle event*/);
emit(state);
//...
```

Note that I'm assuming that `standardAir` and `standard` are not the same.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have decided to use Provider for my UI logic with Bloc doing the backend calculations.